# Dropbox PHP API - direct link expiry set

Tags: php, api, dropbox

Does anyone know how to set an expiry date for Dropbox links via API?

I see there is an setting here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/5888

At the moment all dl.xxxxxxxx.com links expire by default after 4h. I need some permalink solution. I'm using this client at the moment:

https://github.com/f4bsch/DropPHP

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`GetLink`](https://github.com/f4bsch/DropPHP/blob/master/DropboxClient.php#L383) method in the library you're using calls [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) or [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares). Make sure you set the `preview` parameter to true, so that it uses /shares. The links returned by /shares don't expire.

Then, modifying the resulting link as shown here for direct access:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/201